# Get metadata from sharepoint URLs in an excel file

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a flow that can get the "last updated" metadata from a list of links to excel files in an excel file. The goal of the flow is to send an email notifying people if any of the files in the list have not been updated after a certain amount of time.

The issue I am running into is getting power automate to recognize the links as something to get metadata from.

I think the problem is that the link to an excel file in sharepoint (essentially the share link) doesn't really work as a file ID or path. Is there a way to get around this? Either a way to get a file identifier from a URL, or maybe some kind of loop to open the file and then get the metadata? Or maybe some other way to represent the files in the excel list that would be usable?

I know I could just write the flow to get metadata from each individual file, but I would prefer to do it from a list of files in excel (so that I don't have to edit the flow every time I or someone else needs to add a file to the list).

The spreadsheet table with the list of links looks like this: [Spreadsheet of excel links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKtEB.png)

I have tried using the "Apply to each" step followed by the "Get file metadata" step, but I am not able to put in a dynamic File Identifier.

[Get file metadata step example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJrc4.png)

I also looked into using the "Send an HTTP request to Sharepoint" step, but wasn't really clear on exactly what that does and whether it could produce a usable file identifier. I also looked into trying to launch each link in a browser and then get the metadata, but it seems like all the browser related actions are premium (and I don't want to invest in premium options that might not even work).

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

[image]

```js
// Action: FileLink (pick from Dynamic content list)
items('Apply_to_each')?['Spreadsheet Link']


// Action: FileLinkParts
split(decodeUriComponent(split(replace(replace(outputs('FileLink'), '/:x:/r', ''), 'https://', ''), '?')[0]), '/')


// Action: FileSiteAddress
concat('https://', join(take(outputs('FileLinkParts'), 3), '/'))


// Action: FilePath
concat('https://', join(outputs('FileLinkParts'), '/'))


// Action: Get file metadata using path
   // Site Address: Click on the down arrow, scroll to the bottom and select 'Enter custom value'
   outputs('FileSiteAddress')
   // File Path
   outputs('FilePath')
```

You can omit Actions `FileSiteAddress` & `FilePath` and move their respective expressions directly into `Get file metadata using path`.

**Note** - this will not work with "shared links" in the format of:

```
https://example.sharepoint.com/:x:/t/ExamplePlace/LK15n_lIkDHGm9nvX6Jj5WoQuDNpY-jAifhYS9utgLLF7A
```

Comment: Thanks for this info! Follow up question: what is the exact action you are using in this example? When I type in "FileLink," "FileLinkParts," etc. I don't get any results in the action search bar.  Is it one of the "Variable" action types perhaps?

Comment: Those are the `Compose` action. Ensure you rename them as above as these are referenced in other expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This info got me where I needed for my flow.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do what I needed, based on what Sam answered (thanks Sam!)

To get it to work for my shared links (https://example.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/ExampleSiteName/Shared%20Documents/General/ExampleFolder/example%20folderB/example%20filename.xlsx?d=w960973c6352b44140fge28cf7d5c104e&csf=1&web=1&e=hLyqs7), I went to excel for some of the earlier steps. I realize my previous example links didn't really show the file name and type, which may have made things confusing.

I added a column called "Site Address", where I put the first part of the link, deleting the "/:x:/t" so it would only have "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleSiteName"

I added a second column "File Path," where I removed the "Site Address" part of the link, and everything after the end of the file type (starting with the "?") so it would only have "/Shared%20Documents/General/ExampleFolder/example%20folderB/example%20filename.xlsx"

This could be done using Compose steps in Power Automate like Sam shows in the other answer, but for my particular process doing it in excel works too.

Then, in the "Get file metadata using path" action, I can put the "Site Address" from the spreadsheet in the Site Address input, and in the File Path input I can put the formula: "decodeUriComponent(item()?['File Path'])", with 'File Path' being the dynamic data 'File Path' column from my spreadsheet.

This worked, and now I have the metadata I need for the rest of my flow!

See images for my flow below:

[Example Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA5qG.png)

[Overall Flow Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0tw0.png)

[Get metadata Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raGnT.png)

Formula for File Path input: decodeUriComponent(item()?['File Path'])

'File Path' in this is dynamic content from my spreadsheet.